# how to run lighthouse-puppeteer in Desktop mode?

Tags: puppeteer, lighthouse

I'm trying to test using this basic code of lighthouse.
but If I run this code, There are shown with "Mobile" mode.(m.naver.com)
(I wrote a "www.naver.com" but, m.naver.com was redirected)

I want to run at Desktop. Where do I revise the code?
I try to do my best to find a solution, but I couldn't. So Please share your solution. Thanks.

code homepage : https://github.com/addyosmani/puppeteer-webperf

```
import lighthouse from 'lighthouse';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import chromeLauncher from 'chrome-launcher';
import reportGenerator from 'lighthouse/report/generator/report-generator.js';
import request from 'request';
import util from 'util';
import fs from 'fs';


const options = {
  logLevel: 'info',
  disableDeviceEmulation: true,
  chromeFlags: ['--emulated-form-factor=desktop']
};

async function lighthouseFromPuppeteer(url, options, config = null) {
  // Launch chrome using chrome-launcher
  const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch(options);
  options.port = chrome.port;

  // Connect chrome-launcher to puppeteer
  const resp = await util.promisify(request)(`http://localhost:${options.port}/json/version`);
  const { webSocketDebuggerUrl } = JSON.parse(resp.body);
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl });

  // Run Lighthouse
  const { lhr } = await lighthouse(url, options, config);
  await browser.disconnect();
  await chrome.kill();

  const html = reportGenerator.generateReport(lhr, 'html');
  fs.writeFile('report.html', html, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });

  const json = reportGenerator.generateReport(lhr, 'json');

  const audits = JSON.parse(json).audits; // Lighthouse audits
  const first_contentful_paint = audits['first-contentful-paint'].displayValue;
  const total_blocking_time = audits['total-blocking-time'].displayValue;
  const time_to_interactive = audits['interactive'].displayValue;

  console.log(`\n
     Lighthouse metrics: 
      First Contentful Paint: ${first_contentful_paint}, 
     ⌛️ Total Blocking Time: ${total_blocking_time},
      Time To Interactive: ${time_to_interactive}`);
}

lighthouseFromPuppeteer("https://www.naver.com", options);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
const config = require('lighthouse/lighthouse-core/config/desktop-config');


const {lhr} = await lighthouse(url, {
            port: (new URL(browser.wsEndpoint())).port,
            output: 'json',
            logLevel: 'info',
        }, config);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.